# Type 'Future<dynamic>' is not subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, widget, subtype

I am showing markers from API on google maps. Here is my build method. When the program reaches the _widgetbuilder() method, it throws the specific error of type Future is not a subtype of the widget. If someone could please help to solve the problem and also tell me that what exactly this error means.....

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: FutureBuilder<List<MarkersOnMap>>(
    future: future,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'No Properties Added Yet\nPlease Add Some!',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
                ),
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageTransition(
                        duration: Duration(microseconds: 500),
                        type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                        child: AddNewEproperty(
                            createEproperty: widget.createEproperty),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  label: Text('Add'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else
        _widgetbuilder();

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: allWidgets.length + 1,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),],);},);},},),);}
```

This is the _widgetbuilder() method. When it reaches this return _widgetbuilder, throws _typeerror.

```
    _widgetbuilder() async {
    allWidgets = [];
    widget.markersonmap = await future;
    
    widget.markersonmap.forEach(
      (element) {
        print(element);
        allWidgets.add(
          Container(
            height: 25,
            width: 50,
            child: new DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  color: Colors.black54),
              child: Text(
                element.ePropertiesCardsList.price.toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because your function `_widgetbuilder` returns `Future<dynamic>` because the function is async.

```
Widget _widgetbuilder(){
// code here
}
```

The function should be in this structure to return of type `Widget`. The code that needs to be async should either be taken out of build function or use `.then` pattern for async code instead of async await if you really need to.
[This short 9 min video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY&t=277s) will help you understand async better in flutter.

Comment: That was so helpful. Thank you so much SIr! I want to vote your answer but they are not allowing me to. :{

Comment: Glad i could help. You can mark this as correct answer if it helped you. Upvoting is only allowed once the reputation in above 15.

Comment: I have applied this code 
future.then((value) {
      widget.markersonmap = value;
    });
instead of widget.markersonmap = await future;
but when it reaches to .then,  it doesn't fetch data from my api method future which is getdata(){};

Comment: what are you getting in value? if you are not getting anything in value then you might want to recheck and debug your fetching function.

Comment: Previously when I was using async-await, were able to jump to the fetching function but now in .then() method, the program when reaches .then() method it does not jump to the fetching method.

Answer (score 0):

In here now the type error is solved but after reading 'future.then..... it does not goto the future and fetch data but jumps to the next foreach line and then calls it as null.

```
_widgetbuilder() {
allWidgets = [];
// widget.markersonmap = await future;

future.then((value) {
  widget.markersonmap = value;
});
widget.markersonmap.forEach(
      (element) {
        print(element);
        allWidgets.add(
          Container(
// other code
}
```